# xlop: color remainder of opidiv

Tags: color, xlop

I want to color the remainder of \opidiv with xlop using the code below, but all intermediary remainders are colored with the same color :(

Is there a way to only color the last remainder ?

Thank you.

[image: xlop color remainder]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, xlop, xcolor}
\begin{document}
$\dfrac{125}{6} = \textcolor{red}{20} + \dfrac{\textcolor{blue}{5}}{6}$ 
       \hfill \opidiv[voperation=top, dividendbridge,resultstyle=\color{red}, remainderstyle=\color{blue}]{125}{6}
\end{document}
```

Update : problem solved !!!!

the solution is very simple and is described on page 10 of the documentation :

```
remainderstyle.2=\color{blue}
```

Comment: Welcome to the TeX.SE. We can have the  pleasure of a complete code and not a fragment?

Comment: @Sebastiano done

Comment: Well done :-)..

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved.
I found the answer on page 10 of xlop's documentation. the remainders are indexed .1, .2,...etc, and in my example, the last remainder has index of 2 .

```
remainderstyle.2=\color{blue}
```